# Big-O time to generate all letter-replacement words?

Tags: algorithm

Let's say you have a word, such as 'cook', and you want to generate a graph of all possible words that could be made from that word by replacing each letter with all the other letters. An important restriction: you can ask the dictionary if a collection of letters is a word, but that is the limit of your interface to the dictionary. You cannot just ask the dictionary for all n-letter words.

I would imagine this would be a recursive algorithm generating a DAG such as follows:

```
                                          cook
                                   /        |       \
                               aook        ...       zook
                              /  |  \              /  |  \
                           aaok ...  azok       zaok ... zzok
```

And so on. Obviously in reality many of these permutations would be rejected as not being real words, but eventually you would have a DAG that contains all 'words' that can be generated. The height of the graph would be the length of the input word plus 1.

In the worst case, each permutation would be a word. The first level has 1 word, the second level 25, the next level (25*25) and so on. Thus if n is the length of the word, am I correct in thinking this would mean the algorithm has a worst-case time complexity of 25^n, and also a worst-case storage complexity of 25^n?

Comment: This algorithm sounds either incorrect or inefficient. Why is the graph a DAG? Why does the first level start by changing the first letter? Are transitions like fart->farm allowed, without changing the first three letters (or "changing" them to their original values)?

Comment: The graph is a DAG because it's directed and acyclic. The first level starts by changing the first letter because you are generating all possible words by changing the letters in each position to all possible variations. And you will eventually get to fart->farm by doing so ... but you will also generate 'dart', 'fort', etc. by procedurally walking the word. If you have another suggestion as to how to generate all possible word variants I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: If the point is just to find all the words that can be made by changing any number of letters in your original word, you can simply retrieve the list of all words of length n from a dictionnary.

Comment: Let me add the constraint that you only have one interface to a dictionary: the ability to ask the dictionary if a collection of letters is a word. And once again, I appreciate critiques, but I'm really looking for run-time analysis.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better not to view it as a tree, but as a graph.

Let `n` be the input, which is the length of the words.

Let `W` be all the (meaningful) words of length $n$.

Construct a simple graph `G` as follows: the vertices of `G` is `W`; two words `w1` and `w2` has an edge connecting them if and only if they differ by one charater.

Then what you want to do is the following:

> Given a word `w` in `W`, find the connected component of `w` in the graph `G`.

This is typically done with [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (DFS) or [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (BFS). Your algorithm is kind of BFS (but not quite correct: each time you should generate all neighbours of a word, not just those with one place replaced).

Since we may assume $n$ small, the time complexity is theoretically linear in the size of the result (although with a very large big O constant)

However, you should also have an equal size of memory, memorizing which word has already been checked.

Comment: You have seen this before! But you skipped the situation I described and went to the solution for finding the connecting path between the start word and the end word, which isn't what I'm asking .... there's no search whatsoever in the problem I described, just the generation of a word graph.

Answer (score 0):

If you generate only words that can be found in dictionary, then time complexity is limited by the dictionary size, so it should be `O(min(|D|, 25^n))`.